# Is it possible to automatically set UTF16 file encoding when opening a file of that type?

Tags: vim

I edit all kinds of files with Vim (as I'm sure most Vim users do).  One bug bear I have is what Vim does when I come across a file with an odd encoding.  Most editors (these days) make a good stab at detecting file encodings.  However, Vim generally doesn't.  And you have to type, for example:

```
:e ++enc=utf-16le
```

To re-read the file in UTF-16 (Otherwise you get a mass of @ signs)

I've been searching around and have seen scripts like `set_utf8.vim` which can detect a specific file encoding.  However, is there are more general solution?  I'm a bit bored of having to manually work out what the file encoding is and consulting the help every time I open an unusual file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding the encoding name to `'fileencodings'` should do the trick:

```
:set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-16le,utf-8,default,latin1
```

Alternatively, there are plugins like [AutoFenc](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2721) and [fencview](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1708).

Comment: +1 These look very useful, although sadly don't work on my BOMless UTF16 log files, ah well, I'll just add a specific AutoFileCmd for those...  Thanks though!

Comment: On Mac OSX Catalina, using "VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 macOS version" adding this causes all UTF-8 files to be opened as UTF-16 LE

Comment: Word of warning that this affects all UTF-8 files (as @mropp mentioned) and it's not just macOS-specific.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code to your *.vimrc*:

```
if has("multi_byte")
  if &termencoding == ""
    let &termencoding = &encoding
  endif
  set encoding=utf-8
  setglobal fileencoding=utf-8
  "setglobal bomb
  set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif
```

Comment: This works great.  Alas, I am working on Windows c# files created by VS2017 as well as ordinary text files and python from Linux.  Vim does the right thing in opening each file.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a byte-order-mark ? Vim should detect this and work appropriately. From [the doc - section 45.4](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_45.html):

> When you start editing that 16-bit Unicode file, and it has a BOM, Vim
>   will detect this and convert the file to utf-8 when reading it.  The
>   'fileencoding' option (without s at the end) is set to the detected
>   value.  In this case it is "utf-16le".  That means it's Unicode,
>   16-bit and little-endian.  This file format is common on MS-Windows
>   (e.g., for registry files).

Comment: Hmm, this particular file doesn't have a BOM (which is odd on Windows) good to know that this would work on files with a BOM though...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Gvim on Windows, file

    >xxd .\utf16.txt
    00000000: fffe 4100 4200 a300 2400 ac20 6300 6400  ..A.B...$.. c.d.
    00000010: 6500 0d00 0a00                           e.....

When I do "gvim utf16.txt" I see `ÿþA^@B^@£^@$^@¬ c^@d^@e^@^M^@`...  (sorry for formatting, no idea how to do preformatted text in a comment...)