# converting the bad file into correct format

Tags: linux, unix

i have a file file.txt. it shows different junk values when i use cat and vi like below

### cat file.txt

```
▒▒1|2017823|941793|476947|2018-09-11 14:37:21.933|45.9000|9|107103|107103|28|SOUTH
```

### vi file.txt

```
ÿþ1^@|^@2^@0^@1^@7^@8^@2^@3^@|^@9^@4^@1^@7^@9^@3^@|^@4^@7^@6^@9^@4^@7^@|^1^@8^@-
```

is there any way to make this file in a readable output.

i tried this but doesn't seems to be working.

```
sed 's/\x1a//g;s/\xef\xbf\xbd//g' file.txt
```

Comment: The file might have UTF-16 encoding. Maybe answers of this question:   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970395/is-it-possible-to-automatically-set-utf16-file-encoding-when-opening-a-file-of-t) helps.

Comment: This looks like a UTF16 file. Use iconv.

Comment: Some might argue the vi format is readable.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.