# How to make vim display half-width spaces correctly

Tags: vim

I am editing some files that include Khmer text.
And vim does not show the strings correctly.

### The actual text: `១៥.១ ស្រៈ​ពេញ​តួ`

### How it looks in vim:

[image: vim]

The encoding of the files is utf-16le.

Emacs is good on a Linux machine and Notepad in Windows. Just vim has this problem.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970395/is-it-possible-to-automatically-set-utf16-file-encoding-when-opening-a-file-of-t)?

Comment: Vim seems to detect correctly the file encoding (i.e. utf-16le).

Comment: I assume you have tried ":set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-16le,utf-8,default,latin1" as per the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the command.

Comment: If you put the text above in a new vim document, will it be display correctly?

Comment: No. While you are in a document, follow these steps to give it as a command. 1. ESC, 2. :set fencs=ucs-bom,utf-16le,utf-8,default,latin1. The commands appear at the bottom of the document (not in the document). I am not sure whether we are on the same page.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the Khmer text. If you copy it on your machine will it show correctly in vim?

Comment: Didn't work for me also.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds (NOT the answer to your question):

1. Replace <200b> with a space(`:%s/\%u200b/ /g`) or nothing (`:%s/\%u200b//g`) in *Vim*.
   [Credits](https://gist.github.com/zeroed/47bb4c46b1dc10507cfe)
2. Do replacements using sed in *terminal* (`sed -i "s/$(echo -ne '\u200b')//g" name_of_the_file`). [Credits](https://superuser.com/questions/887161/remove-200b-character-from-text-file)

[Something about special Characters in Vim](http://thenickcox.github.io/2013/01/30/new-post/)