# vim - open utf16le file not show character correctly

Tags: vim

In win10 terminal, if I open a utf16le text file, I have run another command:

```
:e ++enc=utf16le
```

to show text correctly.

How can I add a config to `_vimrc` to detect file encodings correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to automatically set UTF16 file encoding when opening a file of that type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970395/is-it-possible-to-automatically-set-utf16-file-encoding-when-opening-a-file-of-t)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+detect+utf-16

Comment: See `:help 'fileencodings'`.